# Bind a key to search backwards for specific word

Tags: tmux

I want to quickly jump to a python's `Traceback`, I tried this:

`bind t copy-mode \; send-key ?\; send-keys "Traceback"\; send-key Enter`

and this (the last search, good enough for me):

`bind t copy-mode \; send-key ?\; send-key Up\; send-key Enter`

`Up` part doesn't work (via binding or a script), I guess `?` blocks further commands for some reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really sure why Up doesn't work but the other keys do (or don't they? you aren't clear).

Anyway - if your tmux is new enough you can just use `send -X` instead of sending individual keys:

```
bind t copy-mode \; send -X search-backward "Traceback"
```

Or if you need to repeat the last search:

```
bind t copy-mode \; send -X search-again
```

Look at the manual or the existing key bindings (`tmux lsk`) to see the commands.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)